# The successor of an ordinal is also an ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Given an ordinal $\alpha$, I need to show that its successor, i.e., $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ is also an ordinal.

I just barely acquired the concept of ordinal and I am having some trouble.

The following is my work:
Suppose $x\in\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, then we have either $x\in\alpha$ or $x=\alpha$. If $x\in\alpha$, since $\alpha$ is transitive, $x\subseteq\alpha$. If $x=\alpha$, then $x=\alpha\subseteq\alpha$. This implies that $\alpha\subseteq\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, hence, $x\subseteq\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ and that $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ is transitive.

I now need to show that $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ is strictly well-ordered, but I'm struggling and no idea how to go about this.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha+\{\alpha\}$?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I made the changes to $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$. I was thinking of $\alpha+1$ and some how mixed it together. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider a nonempty subset $S\subset\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$. And check what happens in the three cases:

(1) $\alpha\not\in S$.

(2) $\alpha\in S$, $S\setminus\{\alpha\}\ne\emptyset$.

(3) $S = \{\alpha\}$.